# Berkeley Problem in Mathematics question of ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In differential equation section problem $3.1.10$ it is given differential equation $$y'=f(y) $$ where $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ be a continuous nowhere vanishing function. It is asked that deduce the conditions on $f$ under which the solution $y$ exist for all $x\in\Bbb R$ for every initial value $c$.

The same problem is also asked in

[Berkeley problem book in maths problem number $3.1.10.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113607/berkeley-problem-book-in-maths-problem-number-3-1-10)
But I didn't get the clear solution.

As in one of comment it is solved as $F(x) =\int_0^y\frac{1}{f(y) }dy$ and inverse of $F$ is solution    of given ODE.

After seeing this I am not able to conclude under what conditions solution will exist which is defined for all $x\in\Bbb R$ . Please help me to get complete information regarding this question.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you reported from the comment is wrong in its formulation. The correct way would be
$$
F(y)=\int_0^y\frac{du}{f(u)}.
$$
Then solutions are obtained via the inversion of the relation $x+C=F(y(x))$. This is an application of the method of separation-of-variables.

Now there are several simple cases that lead to $\Bbb R$ as domain of all maximal solutions. If $f$ is bounded above by a constant or a linear function, $f(y)\le A+B|y|$, the growth of any solution is exponential at worst.

On the other hand it is known that $f(y)=y^2$ or $f(y)=|y|^\alpha$ with smaller powers $1<\alpha<2$ will diverge to infinity in finite time (this does not exactly satisfy the assumptions, as $f(0)=0$, but $f(y)=1+y^2\implies y=\tan(x+C)$ also blows up). This behavior can be detected in a more general way as the fact that
$$
\int_{y_0}^\infty\frac{du}{f(u)}
$$
is finite for some $y_0$. The same applies to the behavior in direction $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

By the theory of differential equations, a sufficient condition for the existence of a solution for *all* $x,y$, is that $f(y)$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition with a uniform constant for all $x,y$.

A slightly stronger sufficient condition is that $|f'(y)|\le c$ for all $y$ (and $c$ independent of $y$).

So, for example, $y=|y|^\alpha$ does not satisfy this inequality for $\alpha>1$, but $y'=y$ does (and the solution $y(0)e^x$ exists for all $x$).